# Changing between Light/Dark modes doesn't update colors of running app. Theme is applied only after restarting app

Tags: android, android-context, darkmode, android-dark-theme

Run into strange behaviour when trying to add support for dark theme in existing app.

I added `values-night` folder where I added new `colors.xml` with different hex for dark mode. Then I extended from `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar` in AppTheme.

When running the app it takes correct colors depending on the theme already set in the phone. But then when I change the theme and come back to app colors don't change. From the logs I can see that activity and fragment are recreated, so this part is working as described in the documentation.

If I add `uiMode` to configChanges in manifest, then activity is not recreated, instead I get a callback in `onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration)`. But calling this function

```
resources.configuration.uiMode.and(Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK)
```

always returns same value no matter which theme I have set the phone to.

If I restart the app, the current theme of the phone is applied correctly. So it feels like the app is stuck with initial theme (context) that it received upon startup and then never gets updated.

I have Dagger2 setup in my app to inject dependencies and one of the Singletons is `applicationContext`. I removed @Singleton tag from it but it didn't help.

I would appreciate any help in troubleshooting this problem. Could anyone hint where to debug?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem...

Comment: hi @MartinClaesson yeah, I fixed it. The problem was changing configurations of context in `attachBaseContext` method inside Application class. Removing that solved the issue. I can write more detailed answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was in overriding `attachBaseContext` method inside of Application class.

My app needs to be locked to certain Locale, regardless of phone language settings. And to achieve that I created helper function that would accept current context and create a new context by changing locale in configurations. This wrapper function was called in `attachBaseContext` method of `Application` class and `BaseActivity`.

```
// in both Application class and BaseActivity
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
   super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.checkDefaultLanguage(newBase))
}

// in LocaleHelper object
fun checkDefaultLanguage(context: Context): Context {
    val locale = Locale.GERMANY

    Locale.setDefault(locale)

    val configuration = context.resources.configuration
    configuration.setLocale(locale)
    configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale)

    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
}
```

**Removing `attachBaseContext` method from `Application` class solved the issue.** So now locale is changed only in activities and app seems to be working as before. I actually don't know why attachBaseContext was overriden in Application class in the first place. I assume that if `getString` would have been called from `applicationContext.getstring(...)` then there might have been some problems with original phone's locale being used, but I haven't tested that yet. All getString calls are using activity's context as of now.

So the main take away for me was - Don't touch the application context! Hopefully, this solution helps in some way.